# Mathematica on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, mathematica

Can someone explain the connection between *Mathematica* and Ubuntu.
Is it possible to have *Mathematica* on it?
Do you have to pay for it?
How to run *Mathematica* on Sage? (or other equivalent)
Where you can download *Mathematica* for Ubuntu 14.04? 
Is there a way to open *Mathematica* notebook with Sage?

Answer (score 4):

- the connection between Mathematica and Ubuntu.

Mathematica is developed by Wolfram , Ubuntu - by Canonical. These two companies are not affiliated in any way, and their purposes are different.

- Is it possible to have Mathematica on it?

As mentioned in other posts, yes, it is possible, there is desktop version for linux. Refer to the instructions [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453). The installation is done through bash script, so most likely the script will determine your linux distro and install .deb package (which is appropriate for Ubuntu). On Fedora that would be rpm package

- Do you have to pay for it?

Mathematica is proprietary , so yes you will have to pay for it. My university offers free installation of Mathematica since I am a student, so you may want to check with your math or IT department regarding available software.

- How to run Mathematica on Sage? (or other equivalent)

The best option would be to use Mathematica directly on the desktop instead of virtual machine, but if you insist, you might want to have it installed within windows virtual machine.

- Where you can download Mathematica for Ubuntu 14.04?

On Wolfram's official website, but again - double check with your university/college. You may have free student version available.

Answer (score 1):

[It will work on Ubuntu](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html), and you do have to pay for it.

[Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) is a free alternative, as is [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica is a non-free proprietary software, so you have to pay for it in any operating system that you're going to use it. There is a version of Mathematica for linux (Mathematica 10, I think) but you can try open-source alternatives like [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/).

You can try to convert mathematica notebook to open with Maxima with [this Maxima code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ribot/).

Hope it helps.